# Approximating square roots in java using the squeeze theorem

Tags: java, nested, sqrt

Hey guys this is for a homework assignment that is way over my head. My teacher is moving the class very quickly. This is my fourth program I have ever written in java, and I am looking for some advise. I need to find the approximate sqrt of a number to an error of EPSILON defined in my program. However, this needs to be accomplished using the squeeze theorem, and constantly updating my bounds. In java how does one update the values of variables fluidly when they are used throughout? Keep in mind my professor has not gotten to return values yet, so I do not think he intends for us to use them. Keep in mind I am quite the novice, but I have an open mind.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    final double EPSILON = .0000000001;


    System.out.print("Enter a number to find its square root -> ");
    double number = sc.nextDouble();
    double low = 0;
    double high = 0;
    double midPoint = (low+high)/2;
    high = number;
    double midPointSqr = midPoint*midPoint;
    if (number < 0) {
        System.out.println("NaN");
    } else {
        while ((Math.abs(midPointSqr - number)) > EPSILON) {


            {
                if (number <= 1) {
                    low = 0;

                    if (midPointSqr > number)
                    {
                        midPoint = (high+low)/2;
                        high = high/2;
                     System.out.printf("%.6f, %.6f\n", low, high);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       midPoint = (high+low)/2;
                       low = high/2;
                        System.out.printf("%.6f, %.6f\n", low, high);
                    }


                } else {
                    low = 1;

                     if (midPointSqr > number)
                    {
                        midPoint = (high+low)/2;
                        high = high/2;
                     System.out.printf("%.6f, %.6f\n", low, high);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       midPoint = (high+low)/2;
                        low = high/2;
                        System.out.printf("%.6f, %.6f\n", low, high);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you need to update midPointSqr variable whenever you update midpoint variable. So wherever you have assignment statements like

```
midPoint = <something>;
```

you should recopute your square right after that like this:

```
midPointSqr = midPoint * midPoint
```

Another alternarive is to use a function everywhere instead of using midPointSqr variable.

```
double getSqr(double value){
     return value* value;
}
```

so whereever you are using midPointSqr variable replace it with following method code:

```
getSqr(midPoint)
```